# Running scripts in H2 database

Tags: sql, h2

I am using create-drop as the value for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto . I have also created a script since I need to insert some amount of data in by tables before actually performing any sort of testing. However since my schema is getting automatically created as I have used the create-drop mode but the script gets an error and says that no such table exists for the SQL operations I am trying to perform. I think its because the script is running before the tables are being created. How do I make this work ? One option is to use validate and provider a create.sql file to make the schema and then run the scripts. But I want to use create-drop.

```
<properties>
        <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:create.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:data.sql'"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>

        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

</properties>
```